# how to create n- letter counts from a string

Tags: python, string

how can I transform a string in order to get counts of three letters ?
for example, say the string `"i like walking"` to `""i l", " li", "lik" "` and so on ?

what if i want to find out how many counts I have in total and list the times each ones of those appear ?

Comment: a pair of three letters is not a pair

Comment: that's right sorry that was a bad interpretation of what i wanted to say !

Answer (score 9):

A simple list comprehension:

```
s = "i like walking"
triplets = [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s) - 2)]
```

Comment: @glglgl fix'd... this is what happens when you use slices too often :)

Answer (score 5):

```
s = "i like walking"
print [s[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(s) - 2)]
```

Comment: wow ! I was looking for a solution in far more complex ways ! is there a certain way to count how many of this pairs I have in total? what if i want to estimate the probability of each one ?

Comment: You can easily count the result of that list comprehension by just calling `len()` on it, although you can already tell that you'll have (len(s) - 3) triplets in your output anyways. Also... probability of what? Occurrence?

Comment: actually i want to built a probabilistic model for my counts and generate random output according to this model.so i want to collect the total amount of my counts and how times each one of those appear

Comment: That's definitely beyond the scope of this question - but this is a decent start.

Comment: Instead of taking `s[i]`, `s[i+1]`, `s[i+2]` individually and `join`ing them, you can just use the slice `s[i:i+3]`.

Comment: thats right.thanks a lot.you really helped a lot to make a start !

Comment: something else..how can i store these outputs in a list ? i want to use a dictionary in a for statement so i can traverse the keys of the dictionary and get a list of how many times each 3-letter appears

Comment: my_list = [s[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(s) - 2)]

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter` to easily create a "dictionary" of how often each triplet appears: `collections.Counter(s[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(s) - 2))` --> `Counter({'wal': 1, 'alk': 1, ' wa': 1, 'lki': 1, 'ing': 1, ' li': 1, 'ke ': 1, 'kin': 1, 'ike': 1, 'e w': 1, 'lik': 1, 'I l': 1})`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to list comprehensions:

```
>>> s = "i like walking"
>>> map(''.join, zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]))
['i l', ' li', 'lik', 'ike', 'ke ', 'e w', ' wa', 'wal', 'alk', 'lki', 'kin', 'ing']
```

Comment: While it works, it's not very efficient because you make two copies of the string...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> strs="i like walking"
>>> pair_size=3

>>> [strs[i:i+pair_size] for i in range(len(strs)-(pair_size-1))]
['i l', ' li', 'lik', 'ike', 'ke ', 'e w', ' wa', 'wal', 'alk', 'lki', 'kin', 'ing']

>>> pair_size=4
>>> [strs[i:i+pair_size] for i in range(len(strs)-(pair_size-1))]
['i li', ' lik', 'like', 'ike ', 'ke w', 'e wa', ' wal', 'walk', 'alki', 'lkin', 'king']
```

Comment: This skips some triplets (e.g. ' li', 'ike') - OP wants all triplets in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Somethinkg like this should work:

```
result = []
for i in range(0,len(yourString) - 2):
   temp = yourString[i] + yourString[i+1] + yourString[i+2]
   result.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

one more method:

```
mystr="i like walking"
mylist=[]

i=0
while i<len(mystr)-2:
  mylist.append(mystr[i:i+3])
  i+=1

print mylist
```

Comment: `list comprehensions` and `for-loop` should be preferred above `append()` and `while` loop.